# Setting default value of SharePoint lookup column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have been all over the net with this. I have seen several answers that in my mind should have worked. However I just do not see a good way to do it. 
I have a list with a lookup column pulling from another list. I have 4 different workflows on this list and at least two of them require the information in this column to populate in an email. The problem is when nothing is selected in that column my workflows suspend themselves looking for a Json node. In other words that field information has to be present. I have tried populating the field through javascript, jquery, workflows. Nothing seems to be working. Does anyone have any better suggestions? Note: There are over 270 items in the lookup column.

Column Name is Supplier
Value I want to return is |t272|tNone|t Or 272;#None

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel Yang for his post on technet that lookup fields are not supported in SharePoint 2013. I decided to try running a Update item 2010 workflow calling the supplier list to update the main list using only the ID field.I set the workflow to run in the background automatically when an item is created.[image] It worked like a charm. I have provided pictures to show how I did it because a lot of people are asking about this issue.